# IE 8 issue with ajax html editor extender

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

```
Test Color <font color="&#x23;ffcc99">This is Color</font> --> Google Chrome  
Test Color &lt;FONT color=#ffcc99&gt;This is Color -- > IE 8
```

When i save the text using ajax html editor extender with font color change in google chrome it works fine but when i do the same in IE8 the text changes into a different format mentioned above which doesn't work.
How can i solve the same?

Answer (score 1):

This forum post helped me: http://forums.asp.net/t/1751476.aspx

When you read or write the html, just use Server.HtmlDecode(whatever your html is);

Also, on postback, I had to do this:

```
htmlEditor.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(htmlEditor.Text);
```